# How to make custom Mocha reporter synchronize?

Tags: mocha.js

I made a mocha reporter to call REST API after test end.

I have a problem that tests not wait for the reporter to get a response from API but running the next test.

I already used `done` on the parameter of `it` to make mocha run as synchronize.